# Razor like intelliSense in custom razor-based template file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-extensions

I am using [Razor Engine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/), which is a library to render any any file using `razor` syntax, to render *Markdown* files with extension `csmd`. So far everything is working like a charm but I would like to have *IntelliSense* like on a regular *MVC* `razor` file `.cshtml`.

So my questions are:

Can I configure VS' *IntelliSense* to this for me?
Can I build a library (`nupkg`)? In case the above is not possible.
Is it too hard (or even possible) to make an extension `vsix` to accomplish this?